# Meaning of _2 sign in scala language

Tags: scala

What does the _2 mean in the following code? Where can I find the official documentation for this?

```
.. 
@if(errors) {
    <p class="error">
        @errors.head._2
    </p>
}
...
```

Answer (score 28):

The `._2` selects the second element in a tuple e.g.

```
val t = (1,2)
t._2
```

so @errors in your sample appears to be a list of tuples.
You can find the documentation [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) for Tuple2, and there are Tuple3, Tuple4 etc. classes for tuples of size 3, 4 etc. The [scala package documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/package.html) shows the available Tuple types which go up to size 22.

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, I believe _2 is just a field name, representing the 2nd field of a `Tuple2` object.

The underscore is sometimes a bit more magical, however.  It's used as a wildcard in import statements, as a non-assigning placeholder in assignments that need a value for syntax but shouldn't actually do any, and as a variable that should be there but whose value doesn't matter in pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `head` returns a [Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Tuple2)

Answer (score -5):

It's for pattern matching, you can find documentation about it [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120)

edit: I believe its main purpose is to match anything, for example if you do "import http._" it will import everything from that library.

Comment: It is used for this, but is also a legitimate character in a variable name, as in this case.