# Scala map method syntax

Tags: scala, syntax

The code below from http://www.scalaclass.com/book/export/html/1 to do matrix dot product.

I can't understand the syntax between the curly brackets.

- Why are the curly brackets used, not the regular method parentheses?
- Is t an anonymous method?
- What is ._1 and ._2?

Thanks.

```
type Row    = List[Double]
type Matrix = List[Row]

def dotProd(v1:Row, v2:Row) = 
    v1.zip(v2).map{ t:(Double, Double) => t._1 * t._2 }.reduceLeft(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- Why are the curly brackets used, not the regular method parentheses?

Some people prefer to use curly braces when the parameter is an anonymous function. For one thing, curly braces enable pattern matching anonymous functions, whereas parenthesis do not. In this particular example, there's no need for curly braces.

Here's an example where curly braces are required (because of the `case` pattern matching):

```
def dotProd(v1:Row, v2:Row) = 
    v1.zip(v2).map{ case (a, b) => a * b }.reduceLeft(_ + _)
```

Note that the above function accomplishes the same thing as the one in the question, in a slightly different way.

- Is `t` an anonymous method?

No, it is a parameter. Just like `v1` and `v2` are parameters for `dotProd`, `t` is a parameter for the anonymous function being passed to `map`.

- What is `._1` and `._2`?

Methods on `t`. The parameter `t` was defined as being a tuple (specifically, `Tuple2[Double, Double]`, which can be written as `(Double, Double)`), and tuples let you extract each member of the tuple with methods like that: `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, etc.

A `Tuple2` only has `_1` and `_2`, of course. Note that the first parameter is `_1`, not `_0`, because of influence from other functional languages.

Anyway, the `zip` method will convert `Row` (`List[Double]`) into a `List[(Double, Double)]`. The method `map` takes a function that converts the elements of the list (which are `(Double, Double)` tuples) into something else.

Comment: Are `._1` and `._2` really methods of `Tuple2`? I knew them to be fields (as in `TupleN` will have `N` fields from `_1` to `_N`, each being of some type `Ti`.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Sure, they are methods. Scala access pretty much all fields through methods, unless they are declared as `private [this]`.

Comment: Oops. You are absolutely correct. Transparent properties do tend to confuse people used to explicit accessors/mutators in Java, like me :P. Thanks for reminding me again, though...

Answer (score 22):

In this particular case curly brackets have no advantage over plain old syntax, but in general the sweet thing about using curly brackets is that they allow you to write pattern matching expressions inside `map ...`:

so I can rewrite this

```
.map{ t:(Double, Double) => t._1 * t._2 }
```

into this

```
.map{ case(a: Double, b: Double) => a*b }
```

but this will not compile:

```
.map( case(a: Double, b: Double) => a*b )
```

._1, ._2 provides access to first, second, ... N element of N-tuple, as Lee said.

Comment: And you can't have more than one parameter within braces.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a very good answer to the differences between braces {} and parentheses () in this question: [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)

For the _1, _2, see [Meaning of _2 sign in scala language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404730/meaning-of-2-sign-in-scala-language).

And yes, `t:(Double, Double) => t._1 * t._2` is an anonymous function (not a method actually). [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: Err, `t` is a parameter, not an anonymous function.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Yes, of course you're right, I mean the whole construct is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets denote an anonymous function which has type `Tuple2[Double,Double] => Double`. The argument is given the local name `t`, so `t` is a tuple of two doubles.`t._1` refers to the first item and `t._2` the second.

Therefore `map` yields a list of the element-wise products of the components of the two vectors, and `reduceLeft` sums these products to calculate the dot product.

Comment: What's the difference between the above and this `List(1,2,3).map(x => x + 1)`

Comment: @Nabegh in this case, there is no difference.